Intermittent Issue with Removing Snapshot View from MapView in iOS
I am facing an intermittent issue with removing a snapshot view from a MKMapView in my iOS app. The snapshot view is added to the map view as there was a white screen while the satelite view is loading after getting back to foreground from background, but sometimes the screenshot does not get removed as expected. The issue does not occur consistently, which makes it challenging to diagnose.
Below is the relevant code:

Adding the Snapshot:

@objc func setForegroundLoader() {
    mapViewSnapshot = mapView.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)
    
    if let snapshot = mapViewSnapshot {
        snapshot.tag = 1001 
        mapView.addSubview(snapshot)
    }
}


Removing the snapshot with a Delay

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) { [weak self] in
    self?.removeSnapshot()
    self?.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.7) { [weak self] in
    self?.removeSnapshot()
    self?.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}


Snapshot Removal Method

private func removeSnapshot() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        
        if let snapshot = self.mapView.viewWithTag(1001) {
            snapshot.removeFromSuperview()
            self.mapViewSnapshot = nil
            print("Snapshot removed successfully")
        } else {
            print("No snapshot found at \(Date())")
        }
    }
}

Main issue is occasionally, the snapshot view is not removed as expected, leading to leftover snapshots on the MKMapView. Please check the screen recording of the situation.
Any insights or suggestions to resolve this intermittent issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Two questions: First, why do you remove the snapshot view twice, once after 0.1 seconds and then again in 0.7 seconds? That doesn’t make sense as you can only remove it once. Second, setForegroundLoader stores the mapViewSnapshot in a property, and removeSnapshot sets it back to nil, but the code never uses that mapViewSnapshot again. Do you have some code that you haven’t shared with us that is doing something conditionally on the basis of whether mapViewSnapshot was nil or not?

If the code does anything conditionally on the basis of this mapViewSnapshot is nil or not, that could be the source of the problem: If you called setForegroundLoader before the prior one was removed, the first snapshot’s removeSnapshot will have set mapViewSnapshot to nil, messing up your state logic for the second snapshot. There is not enough here in the question for us to confirm this, but it is a common mistake when using a smiple state property to keep track of multiple “overlay views” that may chronologically overlap.

That having been said, your video/gif is manifesting a completely different problem from “multiple snapshots”. The view snapshot includes subviews (e.g., the compass, etc.) and you are clearly subsequently updating these subviews on top of a snapshot that has the old rendition of these subviews. Why are you using a snapshot view at all? And if you want a snapshot of the map view, alone, you might consider using MKMapViewSnapshotter rather than the UIView snapshotView technique.
